# I can not see some texts on Unity 3D

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

In my Unity GUI, some of the texts in the engine can not be seen. I have attached some screenshots from my Recorder and Package Manager. How can i fix this, is there anyone that experienced that kind of glitch?

I am using Unity 2020.3.21f1 on the latest MacOS.

[image: Recorder]

[image: Package Manager]

Comment: I used to had the same issue and I just simply exit Unity and re-open it again and it was all fixed.

Comment: @PavlosMavris unfortunately its been going like this for couple of weeks now...

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting unity, and if it does not work, try restarting your pc. Any recently added unity mods might also cause this. Wish you luck!

Comment: I feel like this answer could have been left as a comment under the original post instead of as an answer. Thank you for your first SO answer though!